# When did Java get a JIT compiler?

Tags: java, history

When did Java first get a JIT compiler for production code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Borland had the first one followed shortly by Symantec.  Sun licensed the Symantec one.  Symantec demoed theirs in March of 1996.

Answer (score 9):

http://java.sun.com/features/2000/06/time-line.html

October 25, 1996
Sun announces first Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler for Java platform

Also, from wikipedia: Since JRE version 1.2, Sun's JVM implementation has included a just-in-time compiler instead of an interpreter.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(Sun)

Comment: This is incorrect, in that Borland and Symantec had them earlier.  Also Sun licensed the Symantec one.

Comment: 1.1.5 had the Semantec JIT, but was not a good release. jview and others were already there. In particular Netscape had had the Semantec JIT for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I believe HotSpot debuted in 1.3, though it was available as a plugin to 1.2.

More info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot

Comment: The original C2/server HotSpot was available for 1.2.2 sometime after it shipped.

Answer (score -1):

Define production :) Hotspot had JIT.

Comment: Production: You would be confident enough to tell your boss that it should be used for a program the company depends on.

Comment: That wouldn't be anywhere near the time period of the early jit compilers, imo.

Comment: Hi, I think this would have been better as a comment on the question. And the answer could be edited into the question. I recognize that this thread is quite old and SO has changed over time, so sorry for poking this ;-).