# "If" statement, constant equality

Tags: java, c++, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of condition checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776478/order-of-condition-checking)

When i read some source codes, the if statement is coded in this way,

```
if (1 == a) {
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
if (a == 1){
    ...
}
```

I read a programming book about the advantage of this way, but cannot remember exactly what it is about. Any one know about this ?

(Sorry if this question disturbs you :-) )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of condition checking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776478/order-of-condition-checking) and [Which is more effective: if (null == variable) or if (variable == null)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021195/which-is-more-effective-if-null-variable-or-if-variable-null) and [many](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=if+condition+order) [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=if+yoda)

Comment: @bubuzzz - Actually in case of java the "Yoda condition" is not relevant as javac will produce an error regardless of `1=a` vs `a=1` in an if statement. For C/C++ I know it is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage is compiler will tell you that error right away. For example, `a = 1` will compile but will produce an error at run time whereas `1 = a` will produce an error at compile time since `1` is not a valid lvalue.

Example: this will produce an error right away:

```
       int a = 0;
       if(1 = a) {
        print("test");
       }
```

Whereas this will compile (warnings may be produced depending on the compiler) but it will cause issues at run time.

```
       int a = 0;
       if(a = 1) {
           print("test");
       }
```

The main idea here is to make certain that you are using `==` in a condition instead of `=`.

That being said every modern compiler (ie. Eclipse) will treat the above as an error now. So it's not as big of a deal as it used to back in the notepad and vi days (in my opinion). I personally prefer the `a == 1` since that seems more readable to me.

Comment: @John - Not it's not unless 1 is defined as a variable. Read my post.

Comment: a=1 will give you a big fat warning at least :)

Comment: @Vlad - yes true depending on the compiler ... old gcc compilers didn't even warn on that back in the days. Got beat by fat fingering in vi a lot :P

Comment: No i just tried it, it works, I've always thought you couldn't do that, lesson learned

Comment: @John - Cool, thank you for taking the down vote back :)

Comment: no i upvoted, its been an up vote from the beginning, i up voted because i was wrong and i learned something that I'm going to use from now on, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

In classic C, where a condition is an integral expression, it's very easy to write

```
if (a = 1)
```

by mistake. The problem is that if you do it, the compiler won't complain, since the assignment evaluates to an integer, too. Writing the expression backward makes it such that if you make this typo, the code won't compile. It's not a bad idea to do this in C; it makes much less sense in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out an `=`, `1 = a` is a compiler error, whereas `a = 1` is a subtle mistake.