# Is there any reason to use null == value condition in java?

Tags: java

I am seeing this a lot in someone's code: null-check conditions are written like this:

```
if (null == value)
```

rather than

```
if (value == null)
```

I don't think there is any reason to have the `null` precede the operator in Java. Is there any benefit to doing it this way? Is this simply a case of a C++ programmer applying his skill to Java incorrectly, or am I missing something important?

Comment: do you have example code? i dont really understand the question... sorry

Comment: @MatiasCaamaño `if (null == value)` rather than `if (value == null)`

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021195/which-is-more-effective-if-null-variable-or-if-variable-null

Comment: Just a note for SO, please re-ask the question in the body of the post, and not just as the title.

Comment: @Vulcan Thanks for the aclaration!

Comment: People we do need 8 answers answering the wrong thing. The reason is to make sure we we do not write `value = null` instead of `value == null` since `null = value` would catch the error.

Comment: @skynorth - in fact, it isn't the case at all. I'm aware of the difference (hence the mention of c++ programming in the original question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a case of so-called ["Yoda Conditions" (item #1)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html). Although it is possible to rationalize them in C/C++, there is no reason to use them in Java.

In C/C++, expressions of any type can go into `if`s and `while`s. Writing

```
if (var = NULL) // No compile-time error in C/C++
```

instead of

```
if (var == NULL)
```

is a common error among novices. Yoda conditions were supposedly a remedy to address this problem, at the cost of "Yodifying" your code: C/C++ would trap assignments to `NULL`

```
if (NULL = var) // Compile-time error
```

but "reversed" `NULL` checks are OK:

```
if (NULL == var)
```

Since Java considers non-boolean expressions inside control blocks of `if`, `while`, and `for` to be errors, it would trap `var = null` in place of `var == null`, triggering an error. Therefore, there is no reason to give up readability by "Yodifying" your expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you only want to print the contents of a String if it's longer than 20. You'll do this:

```
if (str != null && str.length() > 20) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

leaving out this `str != null &&` would throw a NPE if `str` actually were `null`.

If you are referring to the difference of

```
if (str == null) { ... }
```

and

```
if (null == str) { ... }
```

there is none.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO! 
There is absolutley not any need to prefer `if (null == value)` instead `if (value == null)` in java!

The check of `if (null == value)` , is a bit strange, at least in java, coming from code guidelines in C and C++, where that make sense.

I like more `if (value == null)` which is better readable.

The reason is to avoid the C/C++ error `if (value = null)` instead of correct `if (value == null)`

If you use `if (null = value)` the C/C++ compiler will throw an error.

However in java, even `if (value = null)` would be a syntax error.
So dont use that `(null == value)` in java

Comment: i don't think this is true... in an `if` block you'd have a compiler error for value = null -- that is, if (value = null) won't compile

Answer (score 1):

It may read better some times

```
if( null == someFunction(someParameter, anotherParameter) )
```

vs

```
if( someFunction(someParameter, anotherParameter) == null )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's typically an artifact of the developer's native language. Some languages have rules make `null == value` more natural than `value == null`. Syntactically, they are the same to Java.

Comment: No, it is not the reason that there exitsts languages where "null == value" is more natural. It is simply a coding gudeline, to avoid accidently omitting one "=" instead of correct the "=="

Answer (score 0):

*Not* checking could mean a null pointer exception.

Placing it in this order helps you not confuse = (assignment) with == (equality).

both

```
if (a = null)
```

and

```
if (a == null)
```

will compile; however, you probably want the second and not the first.

If you flip them,

```
if (null = a)
```

will not compile, while

```
if (null == a)
```

will compile.

Thus you can catch a small, hard to find error at compiler time.

Comment: Indeed, but this doesn't answer the (interpreted) question about the difference between `null == value` and `value == null`.

Comment: Edited my answer... Live long & prosper.

Comment: Decent answer now, but `if (a = null)` will not compile (unless `a` is a Boolean, but rarely are those set as null).

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that you are not assigning a value for eg like `value = null` if you ommit == so this code will compile fine and it can be identified only during runtime, but if you try like this `null = value` this even won't compile.

Comment: this isn't true... whatever if block i'm in will not compile with this

Comment: @bharal null = value will not even compile, it will throw compiler error