# Is there any difference between (null == var) and (var == null)

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I want to know differences between two conditional expressions  `null == var` and `var == null` in if statement of Java.

Comment: `null==var` called  [Yoda condition expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). `var == null` can be misspelled as `var = null` code will run but if `null==var` will misspelled then it would be compilation time error. Read also [Criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions#Criticism)

Comment: Don't try with equals ;)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The most possible reason,You should write that as as anwer.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ lets add my comment in your answer. usually I rearly answer Java's questions.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference.Simply a matter of style.

And the first one called as [yoda style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

> In programming jargon, Yoda conditions (also called Yoda notation) is a programming style where the two parts of an expression are reversed in a conditional statement.

---

Although both conditional expressions `null == var` and `var == null` are equvilent. But suppose if you introduces bug by misspell `==` (check equality ) as `=` (assignment) then `var = null` doesn't give you can error and introduce a bug in your code. Whereas you write `null == var` and suppose misspells `null = var` it produce a compilation time error. And a compilation time error is a way better than a runtime error. That's one of the advantages of the Yoda conditional form.

But I also suggest you read [Criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions#Criticism) of Yoda continuations:

Many Programmers hate it, as it has to  mentally re-reverse it to understand it. (Others obviously don't have that issue). The practice is referred to as "Yoda conditions". Most compilers can be persuaded to warn about assignments in conditions anyway.

Comment: For mentioning the Yoda condition, +1 you get.

Comment: Well.. correct..I think now it should be helpful for OP :)

Comment: @suresh In Java: Is `if(var == NULL)` is  same as  `if(!var)` **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Nope.To successfully compile the statement  if(!var), here  `var` must be a boolean type. Where as in condition if(var == null), `var` can be any object reference.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Oh we can do this in C/C++, so I wanted to suggest OP that right `if(!var)` instead of `null == var` and `var == null`. But not possible in Java.

Comment: Yes.If OP do `if(!var)`,OP land up in a compiler error that states `The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) var`, If it a object reference,other than a `boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

There are no difference.
for example consider the following piece of code

```
String x = null;
if(x==null)
{
    System.out.println("null");
}
if(null==x)
{
    System.out.println("no diff");
}
```

**output**

```
null
no diff
```

This means that there are no difference

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at this:

[Which is more effective: if (null == variable) or if (variable == null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021195/which-is-more-effective-if-null-variable-or-if-variable-null)

Comment: Good link but better to mark duplicate then post it as answer. +1 as I think you don't have privilege to mark duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not. Both statements are true exactly when `var` is `null`.